# Capture group via regex; then run a different regex on captured group

Tags: python, regex

I have a log file that's filled with run time information for a program. If it fails it generates a typical python stacktrace.

I'd like to extract the whole stack trace, trigged by 'Traceback (most recent call last):' into a regex group, and then run another separate regex to grab the last line, usually something like KeyError: Something blah blah.

I have two questions that I have not been able to find answers on, is it possible to use regex to find the Traceback line, and if it exists grab everything from that line to the end of my file?

And if so, can I run a different regex on a captured regex group?

Comment: Sure, but if you just need the last line, why a regex? Wouldn't `captured[0].split('\n')[-1]` do? - this assumes you're capturing the whole traceback in one go, thus `captured[0]`

Comment: Normally yes, the end of my log file has some additional info that I'd like to capture for some other processing as well, so the last line of my log will never be the last line of the stack trace as you would normally see.

Comment: Anyway, the regex group can return the captured text as a string, and you can run a regex on that. There must be something I'm missing, because I can't see the problem

Comment: Ah I see, I believed the captured regex match to be a simple regex object, the other thing I'm not that sure of is how to capture everything a regex match..

Comment: Is there a newline at the end of each traceback in your log file?

Comment: The regex matching/searching function returns a non-string object, **indeed**, with a `.groups()` method returning a tuple of captured strings. That was my original point

Answer (score 0):

This should be the most obvious. Try always to give (code) examples about the circumstances in this case for example your concrete log structure.
Checkout the [regex](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) documentation.

```py
import re

test = """
some stuff
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "x.py", line x, in <module>
    raise KeyError("foo")
KeyError: foo
some stuff
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "y.py", line y, in <module>
    raise KeyError("bar")
KeyError: bar
some other stuff
"""

match = re.findall(ur"^Traceback \(most recent call last\):\n(.*?^KeyError: (.+?)$)$", test, re.DOTALL|re.MULTILINE)
for traceback, error in match:
    print "\n".join(a.strip() for a in traceback.split("\n"))
    print error.strip()
```

Hint: .*? is a non-greedy match, that means it tries to match as less as possible. Otherwise it matches stuff between two tracebacks.

Results in:

```
File "x.py", line x, in <module>
raise KeyError("foo")
KeyError: foo
foo
File "y.py", line y, in <module>
raise KeyError("bar")
KeyError: bar
bar
```